# Asset pipeline in rails3 - application.js not including other js files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

So my application.js file is including jquery accordingly, and everything I've put directly into it.

However, one of my controllers - lets call it Books - has its own books.js file

I want the books.js file only to be present when viewing pages within the books controller.

It doesn't seem to be including it at all though - any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline

Second in app/assets/javascripts/application.js

does it contain something like

```
//= require_directory .
```

or

```
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
```

Comment: ps - the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) on the asset pipeline is an excellent read

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the concept of it loading all js files in app/assets/javascripts on its own?

Comment: @tybro not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

"everything I've put directly into it." ...does that mean you put your own code into application.js? If so, you might want to read a tutorial on the asset pipeline.

But anyways, sounds like `//= require_tree .` is missing.